# About conversions on Solidity 0.8.X - Ethernaut Gatekeeper One

Tags: solidity

I would love to get some explanation over the Ethernaut level `Gatekeeper One` as I am now doing it and have some questions. When trying to get over the `gateThree` at first it was difficult for me to understand, now that I get it, I realized that we can not now convert from `address` to `uint64` as it is done in the modifier.

I now that I have to mask the bytes for me to get the answer expected, I have no problem with that right now. I would just love to know:

1. Since which version the conversions from `address` to `uint` are not allowed or why they were allowed before?
2. What implications does it has in real world implementations out of the level of Ethernaut?

Thank you very much, I am just really trying to undertand as much as I can from each level, I will just use an older compiler to surpass the level and that is it for now...

In case someone does not know about the Ethernaut level I will leave the code here below, I am asked to get through the 3 modifiers:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract GatekeeperOne {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  address public entrant;

  modifier gateOne() {
    require(msg.sender != tx.origin);
    _;
  }

  modifier gateTwo() {
    require(gasleft().mod(8191) == 0);
    _;
  }

  modifier gateThree(bytes8 _gateKey) {
      require(uint32(uint64(_gateKey)) == uint16(uint64(_gateKey)), "GatekeeperOne: invalid gateThree part one");
      require(uint32(uint64(_gateKey)) != uint64(_gateKey), "GatekeeperOne: invalid gateThree part two");
      require(uint32(uint64(_gateKey)) == uint16(tx.origin), "GatekeeperOne: invalid gateThree part three");
    _;
  }

  function enter(bytes8 _gateKey) public gateOne gateTwo gateThree(_gateKey) returns (bool) {
    entrant = tx.origin;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since Solidity 0.4.24, you need always to cast fully :
address(uint160(x)) with x:uint256

The idea is to avoid ambiguity

From the Solidity Doc:
If you convert a type that uses a larger byte size to an address, for example bytes32, then the address is truncated. To reduce conversion ambiguity version 0.4.24 and higher of the compiler force you make the truncation explicit in the conversion. Take for example the 32-byte value 0x111122223333444455556666777788889999AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFCCCC.

You can use address(uint160(bytes20(b))), which results in 0x111122223333444455556666777788889999aAaa, or you can use address(uint160(uint256(b))), which results in 0x777788889999AaAAbBbbCcccddDdeeeEfFFfCcCc.